# Difference between "derogation" and "inferiorization"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

If both *derogation* and *inferiorization* can be used to describe an insult, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Any reason for the -1?

Comment: We create a derivation when no word exists with the requried meaning. Existing words have well-worn meanings and generally understood connotations. Newly-derived forms suffer from want of such support.

Comment: If *beautiful* and *intelligent* can both be used as compliments, what's the difference between them? Your question should at least **show** some research effort. What does a dictionary say? Why is that unclear?

Comment: If *derogation* can but shouldn't be used to describe an insult, and *inferiorization* can't be used since it isn't a word, the difference is in the mind of the inventor, whose responsibility it is to explain.

Comment: @Matt it's already answered, what is your point here? And if you read the comments, you will see that I gave more information about it.

Comment: My points are: 1. why would the two words mean the same thing? 2. The question should contain all the information required to answer it - including your research.

Comment: 1) This is why I asked the question. 2) Noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "used as insult", you apparently mean "used as means of insult". 
If we suppose that *inferiorization* is a word, and that it means "process of making something inferior", the first of the two most-common senses of *[derogation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/derogation)* actually is quite close to that same meaning.  The two common senses of *derogation* are

- something that belittles; disparagement
- (law) The act of derogating; the temporary or partial nullification of a law

The text about racism (mentioned in a comment) may be using *derogation* to refer to speech or actions that belittle (underrate) persons, and *inferiorization* to speech or actions that cause people to become or seem inferior.

Commonly, *[disparage](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/disparage)* would be used instead of *derogate* for the sense in question, and *disparagement* instead of *derogation*, and *inferiorization* completely avoided.

Answer (score 2):

"Derogation" is a real word - meaning the partial revocation or limiting implementation of a law.

"Inferiorization" is what you get when you start adding extra endings to a perfectly good word to make your subject sound more serious and academic.

Comment: I'm helping someone here who is trying to analyse racism in a text by identifying derogation, intimidation, inferiorization, and exclusion. She's still struggling with the difference between the 1st and the 3rd.

Comment: @daniel - they mean whatever the author wanted them to mean. Although as a guide, any author that makes up words to make the essay sound more academic probably isn't worth reading.

Comment: @Daniel: Mostly I agree with mgb that "inventing" *inferiorisation*, and hoping the reader will meaningfully distinguish this from *derogation*, is hardly a sign of good writing skills. I imagine your writer wants to distinguish purely derogatory language like *fucking black bastard* from more explicit "dehumanisation" invoking negative qualities supposedly associated with particular races. Doubtless such a distinction *can* be made (perhaps I've just done it), but it's a bit optimistic to expect just the nonce-word *inferiorisation* to convey this to the average reader.

Answer (score 0):

This responder’s answer demonstrates that he does not understand either how words become words or the difference between a transitive verb and a noun.
Derogation is a noun. Inferiorize Is a transitive verb. They are used very differently.
When I was growing up the word “ain’t” was not in the dictionary. Teachers used to say, “Ain’t ain’t in the dictionary,” to try to get kids to stop using it. Due to the sheer colloquial usage of it, “ain’t” was soon found in the next editions of the dictionary.
Words that are used well and fill a niche almost always become “real words.”
Had the responder been aware of these things his answer would not have been so pointed, judgmental, or wrong.

Comment: When you say "This responder’s answer" which are you referring to? StackExchange changes the order of answers (depending on up and down votes, and acceptance of answers) so you cannot rely on the display order to clarify your reference. Also this is more of a comment on another answer than an answer to the original question.